# sql: JSON_QUERY() function to extract objects

Tags: sql, json, database, google-bigquery

I have a field in my dataset that include json objects in the following format:

| cars |
| --- |
| [{"element":{"name":"honda","id":"34"}}] |
| [{"element":{"name":"Lexus","id":"56"}}] |

I am using the following query to extract the names of the cars, but just returns empty (null) rows. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
select JSON_QUERY(cars,"$.name") AS car_names
from myTable
limit 100
```

Comment: what is the actual data type of cars, an array or string?
array: ['{"element":{"name":"honda","id":"34"}}']
string: '[{"element":{"name":"Lexus","id":"56"}}]'

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  ( select string_agg(json_extract_scalar(car, '$.element.name')) 
    from unnest(json_extract_array(cars)) car
  ) car_names
from `project.dataset.table`
```

if applied to sample data in your question - as in below example

```
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select '[{"element":{"name":"honda","id":"34"}}]' cars union all
  select '[{"element":{"name":"Lexus","id":"56"}}]'
)
select *, 
  ( select string_agg(json_extract_scalar(car, '$.element.name')) 
    from unnest(json_extract_array(cars)) car
  ) car_names
from `project.dataset.table`
```

the output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to extract a scalar value, You should simply use JSON_VALUE(expression,path)

```
For Example:
```

An object of Info contain a **variable name** and **another object address**,
You can get the value of name by using `JSON_VALUE` as it isn't an object

**BUT**

To get the address, you have to use `JSON_QUERY.`